# How can I loop through a ParseObject collection in my ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parse-platform, parse-dotnet-sdk

I am querying a list of objects from my Parse server. I want to loop through each one and retrieve a value, given a key.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Parse;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Web.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Task<int> task = HandleMessagesAsync();
        }

        private async Task<int> HandleMessagesAsync()
        {
            var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Message");
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();

            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                var text = item.Get<"text">; // Not sure about this syntax
                Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + text);
            }

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the guide: http://docs.parseplatform.org/dotnet/guide/#retrieving-objects

```
var text = item.Get<string>("text"); // Retrieve a value from field named "texted" with type "string"
```